# Removing $() jQuery wrapper to just get raw JS element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Random *just out of curiosity* question:

Let's say for whatever reason I get an element back from a function

```
$(element)
```

But I want to remove the **$( __ )** jQuery wrapper to leave the regular DOM Element:

```
element
```

**Is this possible?** (I'm sure it'd be smart to test `$(element).length()` to make sure it isn't more than 1 thing inside beforehand too...

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xHj5d/)

Comment: `$(element).length` is much better if you want to check if it has more than 1 element.

Comment: Ah that's what I meant to type, doesn't `.size()` just end up calling it anyway now?

Comment: Yes, but using `.size` is simply an extra function call which is unnecessary.

Comment: Very true, wow this was much more of a newb question than I even expected :/ haha for some reason I've never had to do this before... Is there an easy way to **test** if it is even a jQuery object to begin with?

Comment: Try `alert($('anything') instanceof $);`

Comment: I'm done with noob questions for the day... haha. How'd that cross-domain AJAX thing turn out btw?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
var firstElem = $(element)[0];
```

or

```
var firstElem = $(element).get(0);
```

Calling `get()` without an index gives you an array of the elements.

Reference: [jQuery get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/)

Comment: Sad, I knew about just doing `$(element)[0]` too haha... thank god it's friday I need a break haha. Any reason to use `.get()` over `.toArray()`, or vice versa?

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS: Just to be clear, I don't think epascarello is actually suggesting the form of `$(element)[0]`, which makes no sense to use. You'd only need `[0]` or `.get(0)` when you've been given a previously constructed jQuery object.

Comment: Yeah I know you guys meant that you can break it down by `[0]` the first element.  Appreciate it fellas!

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS: The `.get()` method lets you grab an element at a particular index. If you don't provide an index, it returns an Array of all the elements. The `.toArray()` method only returns an Array. So `x[0]` is equivalent to `x.get(0)` and `x.toArray()` is equivalent to `x.get()`. Advantage `toArray()` has is its meaningful name. Advantage `[0]` has is that it avoids the function call.

Answer (score 6):

DOM elements are stored as properties at numeric zero-based indices, so you access them just like you would for any other object.

```
$jqObj[0];
```

Or get a full Array of elements using [`toArray()`](http://api.jQuery.com/toArray/)

```
$jqObj.toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xHj5d/2/

```
removeJWrapper($('#ohHeyo'));

function removeJWrapper (el) {
    console.log(el[0]);
}
```

Comment: Post code into the message, do not just link to a 3rd party site.